# How to place a sent email copy in my pc

Tags: thunderbird

When I sending email by thunderbird the same leaves a copy in gmail in sent folder.
How can I leave the copy only in thunderbird or in my pc?

Answer (score 0):

Try to  setup a filter Gmail to erase your sent messages. Make a filter with your email address in the "From" field.

Answer (score 0):

In Thunderbird ,

**Options -> Acoount Settings -> Copies & Folders**

in the box "*When sending messages, automatically* "

tick the box **Place a copy in**

and select options in " **"Sent" Folder on**" to ,your *Thunderbird mail address* or *Local Folder*

Comment: have you selected "Cc these email address" and set your mail id?

Comment: I have not selected Cc

Comment: the problem might be    "If your client is sending mail through Gmail's SMTP server, your sent messages will be automatically copied to the [Gmail]/Sent Mail folder" . So can you change your SMTP